# Jenkins add new node

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I am trying to set up Jenkins to make a production deployment. The aim is to allow Jenkins execute git clone, build and deployment etc. on production server.

Jenkins is running on Configuration Management Server (CentOs 7) and Production Server is another Server (Centos 7).

I started by creating a new node in Jenkins with configuration below:

[image]

Then I added Production Server IP address to Jenkins known host like below

```
-bash-4.2$ cat /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
192.168.1.xx ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYblabla=
```

And I confirmed that on Configuration Management server under Jenkins account I could ssh to Production Server.

But on Jenkins the node status is always like this:

```
This agent is offline because Jenkins failed to launch the agent process on it.
```

Node log was like this:

```
SSHLauncher{host='192.168.1.xx', port=22, credentialsId='service account at w', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[02/12/20 20:57:51] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 192.168.1.xx:22.
[02/12/20 20:57:51] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for service_account (credentialId:service_account at webi/method:publickey)
[02/12/20 20:57:51] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[02/12/20 20:57:51] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/12/20 20:57:51] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Could anybody help with following questions:

1. Do I need to install Jenkins on Production Server as well?
2. How to configure Jenkins to run pipeline on
   new node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally figured out:

There is no need to install Jenkins on Production Server;

The reason for SSH connection failure was wrong credentials for Jenkins set up. Essentially Jenkins will execute an SSH connection thus username/password should be used for this. so what I did was to create a new Credential and Jenkins will copy over a JAR file to /var/jenkins directory.

You would also need to change ownership of /var/jenkins directory!